# Target specific commit in gitolite rules

Tags: gitolite

I need to forbid pushing of specific commit (by its sha). Is it possible to do with gitolite configuration?

I tried specifying something like

```
repo    myRepo
        -       794b62a8b1cf4417c8320a261177b43bd5d8331e            = @all
```

But it does not work as intended. I guess that VREFs can help here but I din't find much info on that.

Comment: Do you mean you want to forbid committing on top of that the existing commit 784b62, or do you mean creating it? The former makes some sense, the latter not so much. If the former, is that the tip of a branch, can you just forbid committing to that branch?

Answer (score 0):

You can set in place a **[VREF](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html)** which will list commits pushed and reject the push if one of those commits matches the one you want to block.

Check as an example [`src/VREF/MERGE-CHECK`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/MERGE-CHECK), which does use [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) to list commits.
See [Adding a `VREF`](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#cb-vrefs) to implement and add your own.